# Need simpler way of displaying data without merging cells (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

**Unmerged cells:**
[image: Unmerged Cells]

See attached screenshot. I want to show multiple limits/attachments/premiums for a single Insured/broker/industry.

I've tried merging rows (see below) for Insured/broker/industry but then I am unable to filter and get all the data for each limit. (it only takes the first row)

**Merged Cells:**
[image: Merged Cells]

**Filtered Cells:**
[image]

Having it laid out with all the rows unmerged means I can filter the data, however it makes the page a little hard to read, especially as it gets larger and larger.

Does anyone have any ideas for displaying the data in a different way?

Comment: you can use VB code to merge based on your logic, Out of box all you have is merge fields etc not the way you want to merge, it would have to be done programmatically

Comment: I don't necessarily need to merge, it just doesn't look that great over 1000s of rows. Was trying to think differently for viewing options.

Comment: if merge is not what you want then rephrase your question correctly

Comment: center across selection

Comment: You could use a pivot. Let user select the Insured/broker/industry and display all the line items related to that. Additionally you could add slicers if you are using Excel 2010 and newer.

Comment: @Firee I'm trying to use a pivot currently, but it only takes the limit once if it's repeated (company G has a limit of 25 multiple times, but it only pulls it in once)

Comment: @Kevin : Can you post a screenshot in the comments. There are ways to repeat row items in pivot.

Comment: @Firee This is how far I've gotten. ![Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ASA0HO1.png).

Comment: @others: Please, try to explain downvotes. Especially when you see that a user has put some effort in his question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MACRO!

Method :
View > Macros > Record Macro

[Record Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCjX8.png)

fill all boxes

press OK
And filter data now.

Fo:
View > Macros > Stop Recording

The next time you need to run the macro to be applied in 1 second filter

Methods run the macro:
View > Macros > View Macros

[View Macros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h1HR.png)

You can see all the macros, edit it and run it.
For the work that you've saved in this macro simply click on the Run button